# Disable window transparency for Windows 7 & 8

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-8, transparency

I want to be able to disable window transparency in Windows Vista and newer. I know [there are tools](http://www.wmskill.com/software/how-to-disable-taskbar-aero-glass-transparency-in-windows-8) to do this, but how do we do this programmatically?

Comment: Transparency only, or Aero? Also, Windows 8 has neither

Comment: Most widows in Windows 8 are actually transparent, I.e. show the window background color through the content. try changing the window color and see what happens to chrome and Microsoft word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't complete, but might work pending testing:

Open regedit, go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM

Add DWORD value, name it as "ColorizationOpaqueBlend" without quotes, and set value data to 0.

Restart pc or change theme.

Comment: Erm, wait, this doesn't answer the question.  It belongs at superuser.com

Comment: I want to do this programmatically, not just once for myself.